# Composition series of regular module

Tags: modules, idempotents

Assuming I know all (primitive) idempotents of an algebra $A$, and its centre, is there a way to obtain a composition series for the regular module $_A A$, and the simple modules of $A$?

Comment: Do you have stronger assumptions on your algebra? Is it Artinian, Noetherian, or even finite-dimensional over a field?

Comment: finite dimensional over a field